# Extending IdentityUser with nullable foreign key to another IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a framework which builds on .net core Identity. Let's say I wanted to extend the [`IdentityUser<TKey>`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/IdentityUser.cs#L42) class with a `ParentUserId` property while the developer should still be able to decide which type to use for the `TKey` primary key. This property would be a foreign key to another user, but could be `null` if the user doesn't have a parent.

Using `string` for `TKey` would work without problems because strings are nullable and don't conflict with the `where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>` constraint (although I don't know why). But if the developer decides to use `int`, I'm screwed.

Currently I'm thinking about a solution like this:

```
public class FrameworkUser<TKey, TNullableKey> : IdentityUser<TKey> 
       where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public virtual TNullableKey ParentUserId { get; set; }

    // for better understanding
    public virtual FrameworkUser<TKey, TNullableKey> ParentUser { get; set; }
}
```

But I'm very unsure and don't think it's beautiful.

1. The developer could do something like `new FrameworkUser<string, int?>()` by mistake. Would be great if something like `where TNullableKey : Nullable<TKey>` were possible.
2. I can't constraint `TNullableKey`. **`IEquatable`** doesn't allow nullable value types (i.e. `int?`), although I don't know if this will result in worse performance when used as a foreign key anyway. **`struct`** won't allow strings.
3. Getting the value of `ParentUserId` will differ depending on the type. For instance to securely get the value of an `int?`, I would check for `int?.HasValue` to be `true` and then get it's value from `int?.Value`. The same procedure is quite different for a `string` which could be `null`, empty, or have some chars. This would make switches from one type to another without extra work difficult/impossible.

Another solution could be having two implementations, one for `string` and one for `struct`, but that's not feasible because then I would also need to have two `IdentityStore<TUser>`s and so on.

So, what would you do?

Comment: new FrameworkUser<string, int?>() -> int? can be null, so why would it be a mistake? I thought new FrameworkUser<string, int>()  would be the mistake.

Comment: We will need more code to see the big picture. Can you post the rest of it? I'm afraid we won't be able to do much here with the current code. If this is only hypothetical then I suggest trying [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) that could be better in this case. Code Review requires real and working code.

Comment: @dfhwze It's a reference to another user, so `TKey` and `TNullableKey` must have the same type, but the second needs to be nullable.

Comment: @t3chb0t Well, maybe you are right and I should have posted it there. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @LinusCaldwell It is a very interesting question nonetheless. I get what you want to do now. It cannot be done with generic constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done at design time given generic constraints. Second best option would be at runtime. There are 2 runtime constraints:

1. `TNullableKey` must be null-assignable (reference type or nullable type)
2. The underluying type of `TNullableKey` must be of type `TKey`

code

```
public class FrameworkUser<TKey, TNullableKey> : IdentityUser<TKey>
           where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
  {
      public virtual TNullableKey ParentUserId { get; set; }
      public FrameworkUser() 
      {
          var sourceType = typeof(TKey);
          var nullAssignableType = typeof(TNullableKey);

          if (!IsNullAssignable(nullAssignableType)) {
              throw new InvalidOperationException();
          }

          var targetType = nullAssignableType;
          if (IsNullable(targetType)) {
              targetType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType);
          }

          if (!targetType.Equals(sourceType)) {
              throw new InvalidOperationException();
          }
      }

      private static bool IsNullable(Type t) {
          return t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
      }

      private static bool IsNullAssignable(Type t) {
          if (IsNullable(t) || !t.IsValueType) {
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }
 }
```

Test case

```
public static void Main() {

        // OK
        var a = new FrameworkUser<string, string>();
        var b = new FrameworkUser<int, int?>();

        // Errors
        //var c = new FrameworkUser<string, int>();
        //var d = new FrameworkUser<string, int?>();
        //var e = new FrameworkUser<int, int>();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: If the solution with two generic parameters is the best I can go, this would at least prevent mistakes, so thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea:

Define `FrameworkUser` as:

```
  public class FrameworkUser<TKey> : IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
  {
    // Either you could do this, if ParentUserId is relying on ParentUser
    public virtual UserId<TKey>? ParentUserId => ParentUser != null ? ParentUser.Id : (UserId<TKey>?)null;

    //.. or this, if it is an independent value (Name changed for testing):
    public virtual UserId<TKey>? ParentId { get; set; }


    // for better understanding
    public virtual FrameworkUser<TKey> ParentUser { get; set; }
  }
```

where `UserId<TKey>` is defined as:

```
  public struct UserId<TKey>
  {
    public UserId(TKey id)
    {
      Id = id;
    }

    public TKey Id { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return Id.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator TKey(UserId<TKey> userId) => userId.Id;
    public static implicit operator UserId<TKey>(TKey id) => new UserId<TKey>(id);
  }
```

Test cases:

```
    FrameworkUser<string> stringUser = new FrameworkUser<string>();
    Console.WriteLine($"Witout Parent: {stringUser.ParentUserId}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Witout ParentId: {stringUser.ParentId}");
    stringUser.ParentUser = new FrameworkUser<string> { Id = "ParentId" };
    stringUser.ParentId = "Independent ParentId";
    Console.WriteLine($"With Parent: {stringUser.ParentUserId}");
    if (stringUser.ParentId != null)
      Console.WriteLine($"With ParentId: {stringUser.ParentId}");

    Console.WriteLine();
    FrameworkUser<int> intUser = new FrameworkUser<int>();
    Console.WriteLine($"Witout Parent: {intUser.ParentUserId}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Witout ParentId: {intUser.ParentId}");
    intUser.ParentUser = new FrameworkUser<int> { Id = 1234 };
    intUser.ParentId = 1234;
    Console.WriteLine($"With Parent: {intUser.ParentUserId}");
    if (intUser.ParentId != null)
      Console.WriteLine($"With ParentId: {intUser.ParentId}");
```

Comment: This is a refreshing idea. +1 for thinking outside the box.

Comment: This would be wonderful, but when I try to configure Entity Framework and set `HasConversion()` for the `ParentId` property, it seems to be ignored at the foreign key and EFcore complains about incompatibility with the primary key, or if I let EF do the foreign key config itself, it creates an additional `ParentId1` column for that. I know this should be another question, but maybe you already have a solution for this too. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @LinusCaldwell I would make a new question. EF compatibility was never a requirement in this question :-)

Comment: @LinusCaldwell: See my update

Comment: I already tried option 2 (`ParentUser` is a navigation property for `ParentUserId`), but this creates an additional useless column `ParentUserId1` or complains the foreign key and the primary key are not compatible if I config the foreign key manually. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54196993/2156756) addresses this issue but has no answers. Anyhow, thank you for your effort! It's a great solution. I'll mark it as accepted if I manage to solve the EF issue.